# Application Navigation Framework (SL) with MVVM

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, mvvm

how i can use Application Navigation Framework (SL) with MVVM, I'm use MVVM Light Toolkit..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything special about using the Application Navigation Framework with MVVM. You would just create your standard navigation application in Silverlight and create your views. The Views would need to be tied to the ViewModel in one of the various ways out there such as setting the DataContext of the view to an instance of the VM in the xaml. The navigation framework just loads the views into the frame, the rest of it is just standard MVVM and no different from a standard Silverlight application.

Comment: Thanks Bryant, Can you show me how you use the class Frame in one ViewModel. Becouse I try use HypperLinkButton with Command in Silverlight 4. But I don't know..